# Word counter returning incorrect number of words

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I've been trying to create a program that reads text from a file and stores it in a string. I feed the string to a function that counts every word in the string.

However its only accurate **assuming** the user leaves some whitespace at the end of a line and doesn't creates blank lines.... not a very good word counter.

- Creating a blank line results in a false increment to the word count.

I'm not sure if my main problem is using a boolean to do this or checking for whitespace and '\n' characters.

```
bool countingLetters = false;
int wordCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
{
    if (text[i] == ' ' && countingLetters == true)
    {
        countingLetters = false;
        wordCount++;
    }
    if (text[i] != ' ' && countingLetters == false)
    {
        countingLetters = true;
    }
    if (text[i] == '\n' && countingLetters == true)
    {
        countingLetters = false;
        wordCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a space at the end, something like `text += ' '`

Comment: @justANewbie ahhh I knew it was something painfully obvious i missed thank you. sadly the other issue with blank lines being counted as words persists.

Comment: Consider how many (and which) of the `if` statements bodies will execute when a newline character is found (it isn't one).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm jeez ok thank you, i need to get better at reading if statements or using less of them

Comment: @GarlicBread Well, you just need to decrement `wordCount` when you see a blank line. A quick hack I know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is basically a state machine. To complete your solution, just count in the string ending.

Add this to the end of your code:

```
if(countingLetters) { // word at the end of string, without any space charactor
   wordCount++;
}
```

Or if you can be sure it's C-style string, like std::string, you can just index 1 pass the last charactor, and handle `'\0'`in same way of space and `'\n'` .

To improve your code, use isspace (and this covers more space charactor, including `'\t'`, etc.). And better to use `else if` pattern. Also, it's not good pratice to `==true`. Just use boolean as condition.

Or maybe, `isalpha(c)` fits more to your need.

```
bool countingLetters = false;
int wordCount = 0;
for (char c:text) {
    if (!isalpha(c) && countingLetters) { // this also works for newline
        countingLetters = false;
        ++wordCount;
    } else if (isalpha(c) && !countingLetters) {
        countingLetters = true;
    } // otherwise just skip
}
if(countingLetters) { // word at the end of string, without any space charactor
   ++wordCount;
}
```

And it's not acceptable to insert extra charactor just for such a simple task. For example, text may be const.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to count the *beginning* of a "word".

Let us say the beginning of a word is a letter after a non-letter.  We can adjust this if desired.

```
int wordCount = 0;
int prior = '\n';  // some non-letter
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
  if (isalpha(text[i]) && !isalpha(prior)) {
    wordCount++;
  }
  prior = text[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ also provides some very high-level ways to do this.

One is by using a loop over a stringstream, which splits text on whitespace:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::size_t count_words( const std::string& s )
{
  std::size_t count = 0;
  std::istringstream ss( s );
  std::string t;
  while (ss >> t) count += 1;
  return count;
}
```

Another is using a stream iterator algorithm:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::size_t count_words( const std::string& s )
{
  std::istringstream ss( s );
  return std::distance( 
    std::istream_iterator <std::string> ( ss ), 
    std::istream_iterator <std::string> ()
  );
}
```

Yet another is using a regular expression:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

std::size_t count_words( const std::string& s )
{
  std::regex re( "\\w+" );
  return std::distance(
    std::sregex_iterator( s.begin(), s.end(), re ),
    std::sregex_iterator()
  );
}
```

I’m sure there are many more, but those three are the ones that come off the top of my head.